# How to use one class over another in a div if something is true?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Any idea how I can use one class in a div over another if some condition is true in the middle of the body of an HTML file?

Here is some sample code of what I am trying to do:

```
          <div id="chat-list" class="uk-list" data-bind="foreach: messages">

           <div class="bubble2" data-uk-tooltip title="chat-listitem-timestamp">

                <h4 class="chat-listitem-username" data-bind="text: username"></h4>
                <p class="chat-listitem-message" data-bind="html: content"> </p>
           </div>
          </div>
<script>
                    var currentUser = new chatR.user(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
</script>
```

I would like to use the bubble1 class rather than 2 if  currentUser is equal to username?

Comment: What attempts have you made? This is relatively researchable. You require an `if` statement and then some javascript to change the display of your divs.

Comment: I am new to JavaScript not new to programming I have tried to google... I know how to write an if statement... The problem however is to do this in the middle of the body of a page... FYI, I really hate the javascript community on this site... always -1 every question I have, the point of the site is to ask questions. I love the C# and the rest of it though...

Comment: I don't -1 questions unless it really calls for it, it's not useful to anyone.
It's the way that questions are phrased, just asking people for answers when really all it requires is some mild research. If you are new and still having problems then let people know where you got stuck so that you can learn.
There is a lot of posts on meta about how to structure questions, that's the courtesy of the forum.

Comment: As long as my question is answered I dont care anyway... -1 all day..

Comment: Poor attitude. The etiquette and rules are there for a reason.

Comment: I follow them well I think sorry my JS skills are not up to your standards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/HPcTx/)

```
  function ChangeClass(){
        if ($("#userName").html()=="UserName"){
        $("#userName").addClass("bubble1");
            $("#userName").removeClass("bubble2");
        }
        else{
         $("#userName").addClass("bubble2");
            $("#userName").removeClass("bubble1");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with jquery:

```
  <div class="bubble2" data-uk-tooltip title="chat-listitem-timestamp">

                <h4 class="chat-listitem-username" data-bind="text: username"></h4>
                <p class="chat-listitem-message" data-bind="html: content"> </p>
           </div>
<script>
      var currentUser = new chatR.user(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
      if(currentUser == "yourUser"){
           $('.bubble2').addClass('bubble1').removeClass('bubble2');
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Conditional logic inside view

   ```
   <div class="@(@Model.CurrentUser == @Model.UserName ? "bubble1" : "bubble2")">
   ```
2. View model property

   Code:

   ```
   public string BubbleClass 
   { 
       get 
       { 
           return CurrentUser == UserName ? "bubble1" : "bubble2" 
       }
   }
   ```

   Markup:

   ```
   <div class="@Model.BubbleClass"/>
   ```

Comment: I was unable to get this to work but I don't often work with ASP.NET so it could have just been me but I would have preferred this way of doing it.